# Is there any way to remove redundancy with types in this function?

Tags: haskell

suppose I have two functions like so:

```
food :: Eatable a => String -> a
food animalType = getAnimal animalType

getAnimal :: Eatable a => String -> a
getAnimal "cat" = Cat
getAnimal "dog" = Dog
```

Where `Cat` and `Dog` are both `Eatable`s.

So I can call the food function like this:

```
let cat = food "cat" :: Cat
```

But having the string in there seems redundant. Is there any way to change this to:

```
let cat = food :: Cat
```

Comment: Isn't just removing `String` from `getAnimal` works ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, simply remove the redundant argument. The return type of `getAnimal` determines the instance that will be used.

```
data Cat = Cat
data Dog = Dog

class Eatable animal where
  getAnimal :: animal

instance Eatable Dog where
  getAnimal = Dog

instance Eatable Cat where
  getAnimal = Cat
```